# A Code from the Lines

Tags: lateral-thinking, mazes

Yeah. I think this puzzle will be the hardest puzzle on Puzzling...

I'll add one hint per 3 days, I'll add a VERY helpful tag on the 3rd week, and I'll post the answer and explanation on the 4th week.

Edit: I've completely managed to ignore this...

Yeah, here's the puzzle: (Thanks to @squeamishossifrage)

[image: PUZZLE]

This is the correct way to look at it.
All tangents from the positive x are ±0, undef, ±2, ±1/2, ±1.
Read from top-left to bottom-right
Find the 3-digit code!!!!!

So, what is the three digit code that is described by these seemingly random lines?

Hint:

> This puzzle will have a EUREKA moment, almost like my last puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/what-the-answer-isnt-the-no-of-the-yes-is)

Hint 2:

> The comments below have a lot of helpful hints, especially the ones on March 27

Hint 3:

> Ivo Beckers is missing something else from his picture... For every single one, he has forgotten two lines.

Hint 4:

> The EUREKA moment has nothing to do with math.

Comment: Hmmm, a week between every hint? I think that would make the problem not attractive...I'd suggest a hint every 2-3 days if you want this to be solved slowly.

Comment: Sure, fine, whatever

Comment: @awesomepi I would request you to add the instruction to your question body. It is very difficult to understand what is written on the paper. ... I agree with "Gosh... I suck at writing" :P

Comment: @AshutoshNigam There we go

Comment: I've redrawn the puzzle, but [I need someone to check it for me](http://jsfiddle.net/qzs9p23z/). I can fix errors quite easily, but if you want to do it yourself, the Python source code is [here](http://pastebin.com/TRhVx1u1).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I appreciate the work. I saw one error, but I am on a phone and in not sure whether that's the only one. It is a very important one, however, and cannot be overlooked.The one Six down and seven over is wrong.

Comment: @awesomepi [OK, here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye3VS.png)

Comment: "The hardest puzzle on Puzzling" ... that's a very high bar to aim for! Check out Avigrail's riddles (reciting the words of some of them makes me cringe even now!), or Noctis Skytower's "Justice and Fairness" (with 30 or 40 hints posted).

Comment: @randal'thor I know, It's SUPER high... but I'll have to say, this is REALLY hard. If there's a LOT of interest, I may postpone the dates. Or I might procrastinate.

Comment: @randal'thor I wouldn't know tho, I suck at puzzle solving. I did try my hand at the riddle on the A gold ring? A... one, and that was made in a total of 10 minutes. I make puzzles all the time tho, it's one of my hobbies.

Comment: A thing I notice is that the dots along the border never have lines pointing outwards making me think that you have to extend the lines until they reach another dot

Comment: [This doesn't really seem like it helps but maybe someone does see something in it](http://i.imgur.com/Ou582dS.png)

Comment: @JRichardSnape I'm sorry, that edit was not by me, but I failed to catch the mistake. I also edited the tangents so that it makes more sense.

Comment: @JRichardSnape  The tangent values as given mean exactly what you have in your linked diagram.  The tangent of a horizontal line is 0, a 45° diagonal is ±1, and a vertical line is undefined.  The ±2 and ±1/2 values correspond to the approximately 26.6° and 63.4° lines you drew (*2 over, 1 up* and *2 up, 1 over*). It is just saying that all of the lines are at one of those angles.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I had it wrongly written earlier.

Comment: Could this be a graph-colouring question, with the extended property of first requiring the completion of the graph itself? I also notice only one instance of two lines pointing directly at each other, namely the (4,1) and (5,1) points (where the 1 is the row number). Could this be a hint of some sort?

Comment: @glen and the last node is the only to be 1st order

Comment: @GlenO The two pointing together were not meant to be that way, I'm sorry for the conclusion. I accidentally copied my original version wrong, but no, it does not matter.

Comment: My first thought was that since there's 16 possible positions for a given line, then it might be something encoded in hex, but between the "nothing points off the edge" and "no two lines point at each other", that seems highly unlikely.

Comment: Ivo's graph, while great, seems to have two omissions. The square one right and one down from the top-left; and the square one above the bottom right, both have unextended lines. That's all I have to say, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: @awesomepi When you say "Read from top-left to bottom-right", do you mean left-to-right then top-to-bottom or top-to-bottom then left-to-right? Or would answering this question be a big giveaway ;)

Comment: @Allan None of the above :) It's complicated

Comment: @awesomepi is this some kind of pigpen cipher? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat No, it is not.

Comment: Is there any reason you're spelling it "EUREAKA" rather than "EUREKA"?

Comment: @JoeZ. No, I just suck at typing.

Comment: That being said, does the EUREKA moment have anything to do with the word EUREKA?

Comment: @JoeZ. what are you saying? I just suck at typing... It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I took a look at some of the paths connecting the top left and bottom right, and they seem to have shapes loosely resembling the digits 4, 1 and sometimes 5 appearing. Am I just hallucinating? (Likely)

Comment: @namey I mean, there are an awful lot of lines there; I wouldn't be surprised if you see them.

Comment: it's not 256 is it? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try #4

> (EDITED to reflect the actual answer, although I went with 342 at first)

Could the 3-digit code be

> **345**

because the path resembles those numbers (see below)

> [image]

Comment: I hate to say this (no i don't) but your 2nd option is like claiming there's a face on mars.

We so desperatly want to see patterns that we see them when they're not there. if you want it to to resemble numbers you have to take all the blocks in account, there are many unused blocks below 2 and cel number 5 ruins your 3 not to mention the squigle inbetween 3 and 4.

nicely thought but it is extremely far fetched :P

Comment: The answer is actually 345 based on the shapes, but I'll give it to you.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat It would be a LOT clearer without the boxes.

Comment: @awesomepi I thought about it being 5 at first, but then, the 2 looked so intentional that I changed it to a 2, thinking that the 5 looked a bit weak.

Comment: I really like the first part of the puzzle where you have to realize it's a maze. But the way of turning that maze into a 3-digit number feels arbitrary :/

Comment: @awesomepi the answer is 345? Jlee could you replace the image with a correct one and make it clear 345 is the answer.

Comment: @awesomepi I really like the puzzle overall. The first 2 digits are fine, but the last digit needed to be more clearly a 5. Also, I know a puzzle like this would take lots of time to check before posting, but it would have improved the process greatly.

Comment: I showed the final path to my wife and asked her what 3 numbers she saw in it, and she immediately said 345, so I guess it's more of a perspective thing. (I thought it was 342)

Comment: @JLee except in your edited version there is no reasoning for the path you've taken. So it is still unclear why you took this particular path.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat I have been wondering the same thing. Why THIS path over the others? I honestly don't know. I created this path in response to a hint given by the OP, by combining the 1st part of the path in my 2nd attempt, with the last part of the path in my 3rd attempt. Do you have any insight as to why this path should have been chosen?

Comment: I'm gonna go with the face on mars here. I went over some of the possible paths including this one and while the middle sort of looked like an intentional 4 (and in other paths, it looked like an intentional 1), the others were plain daydreams.

Answer (score 5):

I think the 3-digit code could be

> 269

because

> the graph that is created when the lines are extended to the next dot, has **269** partitions of different sizes and shapes. (thanks to the picture posted in the question's comments by Ivo Beckers, which was missing a couple lines) [image]

Comment: Actually, in the square directly above the bottom-right, you missed a line, which actually brings the total up to 268.

Comment: And in the second from the top, second from the left, making it 269.

Comment: @Joe Yes! good eye! thanks. I started making the connected graph on my own, but then got lazy and decided to use the one that was posted.

Comment: Only this seems disregard the instruction "read from top-left to bottom right", which suggests to me that the answer should be something that can be read digit by digit, but I don't know.

Comment: Nice answer, nice angle, but it's still incorrect.

Comment: @String good point. I thought of that when I was counting, but thought I'd try it anyway, since I didn't have anything better

Comment: @awesomepi Is this a graph coloring problem? if so, can we get some direction? or a hint? if it's not a graph coloring problem, then what level of mathematics is needed to be able to solve it? i just don't want to waste time on a problem that requires some crazy high amount of math knowledge.

Comment: also, was the "Eureka moment" the extending of the lines to the next dot? if not, then is it still unmentioned in any of these comments?

Comment: @JLee It was neither of those actually.

Answer (score 3):

The number is

> 913

Because

> that is the number of different non-self-intersecting paths there are that start in the upper left corner and end in the lower right corner.

Take note that

> the graph is directed. Just because you can go from (0,0) to (0,1), doesn't mean you can go from (0,1) to (0,0). (with the single exception of the fourth and fifth cells in the first row, but they were [a mistake](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10968/a-code-from-the-lines#comment35416_10968)). This was what Ivo Beckers' illustration was missing; "For every single [line], he has forgotten [to add] two lines [to the end of the current line, to make it into an arrow]."

Comment: No... close, but no.

Comment: I posit that it's the number of non-self-intersecting paths that don't end in a single dot.

Comment: I haven't checked, but I suspect that number would be more than three digits long.

Answer (score 2):

Try #2

I think the 3-digit code is

> **991**

Kevin's answer helped me a lot, although I am still not sure this is the correct answer. The shortest path I could find from top left to bottom right is

> 1,13,3,28,29,49,63,52,53,66,79,93,105,118,119,120 which sums to **991**

To get the numbers above, I numbered each cell from 1 to 120, going first from left to right, then top to bottom.
[image]

Comment: crap. i just realized that 5 to 31 is not a path! error due to me working backwards!

Comment: my error is now now corrected!

Comment: Well, nice try, and well crap, I found a typo... God dangit the 79 should not have a path going to 93, but you're on the right track.

Comment: There, it's fixed...

Comment: I guess with that fix, the number will have more than 3 digits now. So maybe, instead of the shortest path in terms of nodes, are we supposed to take the path that yields the smallest number?

Answer (score 2):

Try #3

I think the 3-digit code is

> **216**

I made a dial, based on the layout of a clock, that assigns a value to each of the 16 directions away from a cell.

> [image]

After the last edit to the question, the shortest path (based on summing the values) from the upper left cell to the lower right cell is

[image]

Comment: Close, try combining the first half of your path in the earlier answer to the next half of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too simple, but could the code be

> 107?

That seems to be

> the number of dots that can actually be reached from the top-left square (by following the lines in the original picture, not Ivo Beckers' one, i.e. taking directionality into account as noted in Kevin's answer).